# jQuery sparkline set interval array

Tags: javascript, jquery, sparklines

i have a script for showing span sparkline
like this

```
function refresh_network() {
    var net = window.net = $('.dynamicbar').data('sparkline');
    $.getJSON('<?echo site_url('home / netinfo')?>', function (data)
    {
        var myvalues = [data.value, data.value, data.value, data.value, data.value, data.value, data.value];
        $('.dynamicbar').sparkline(myvalues, {
            type: 'line',
            barColor: 'green',
            width: '100px',
            height: '50px',
            fillColor: false,
            tooltipPrefix: 'RX ',
            chartRangeMin: 10000,
            chartRangeMax: 100000
        });
        var myvalues = [data.value2, data.value2, data.value2, data.value2, data.value2, data.value2, data.value2];
        $('.dynamicbar').sparkline(myvalues, {
            type: 'line',
            lineColor: 'red',
            width: '100px',
            height: '50px',
            composite: true,
            fillColor: false,
            tooltipPrefix: 'TX ',
            chartRangeMin: 10000,
            chartRangeMax: 100000
        });
    });

};

function auto_net() {
    refresh_network();
};

setInterval(auto_net, 500);
```

i have grep network (RX/TX). It change every 0.5 s, but i still confuse to show moving graph like this 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timvasil/2gVUh/1/)

But, in jsfiddle example. It's using ext.js(sencha), and the changing graph algorithm is using math random.

sparkline take parameter array like this [value1, value2, value3,..., valuex], example if i take 3 array  then algorithm [value(now-2), value(now-1), value(now)]. But how to apply this?